# How can I improve this message?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

I'm making some video to spread awareness about coronavirus. In the end, I need to give people a message that along with washing hands, you should also clean your laptop, mouse, phone and similar stuff to prevent infection. Here's what I have:

Option 1: *Keep washing your hands, clean and disinfect your laptop, 
mouse, smartphone etc. daily to prevent infection.*

Option 1(b): *Keep washing your hands; clean and disinfect your laptop, 
mouse, smartphone etc. daily to prevent infection.*

Option 2: *Keep washing your hands, clean and disinfect your laptop, 
mouse, smartphone and similar stuff daily to prevent infection.*

Problem with 1st I see is *etc.daily* which seem like the sentence ended just before *daily*. Is it really so?

To *correct* above, I changed it slightly. But does it make sense? Would *similar stuff* also relate to stuff similar to hand washing? Or only to the latter part of the sentence which is about accessories?

Comment: The abbreviation **etc.** is usually followed by a point/period, which does not mark the end of a sentence. One clue is that the initial letter of the following word is not capitalised. However, abbreviations are also a matter of style, such as **Mr.** (AmE) and **Mr** (BrE).

Comment: Option 1 doesn't bother me, but if you want alternatives, you could write *et cetera* or *(etc.)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of "etc." (and its period) I don't think are really a problem.  This is fairly common (and correct usage) and most people will not be confused by the use of a period in an abbreviation in the middle of a sentence.

There are a couple of comments I would make on other aspects, however:

First, you should have a comma before "etc." as it is a separate element of the comma-separated list (I suppose this is technically a version of the "oxford comma" debate, so arguably it could go either way, but I think with "etc." it is much more common/natural to use a comma than not).

In (1), you are mixing a comma-separated list within another comma-separated list, which can be confusing.  It looks like in (1b) you tried to address this by using a semicolon after "hands", which is one way to distinguish things, but it's subtle enough many people will still miss the distinction.  I would recommend actually using a conjunction like "and" instead:

> Keep washing your hands, **and** clean and disinfect your laptop, mouse, smartphone, etc. daily to prevent infection.

If you really want to avoid "etc." here, "similar stuff" technically works, but "stuff" is a very casual/informal word, and changes the feeling of the whole sentence to be much more "chatty", which is probably not appropriate for serious warnings/advice about a disease.  Some alternatives that might work better:

- and similar items
- and so forth